# Show entire file contents in dialog on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to show the contents of a file on Dialog box for which I have use the "--textbox" dialog and "--tailbox" dialog.

But it doesn't show the whole contents of file, it only shows some of the data.

How do I get it to show the entire file data?

Comment: It is quite unreadable this way. You should not use the code tag (4 spaces at the beginning of the line) for plain text.

Answer (score 5):

It has no sense to use both `--textbox` and `--tailbox`.

Use `--textbox` to display the **whole** file, use `--tailbox` to display only the **last lines** of the file.

For example, the following command will display the content of the whole file `todo.txt` in a dialog textbox of size 20x80.

```
dialog --textbox todo.txt 20 80
```

Comment: i have used --textbox but it just display me the last line of the file...

Comment: It's still the correct answer. Obvious question: does the file really have more than one line or has it been truncated by something else?

Comment: ya the file has more than one line ofcourse....

Comment: Have you tried with different files and different terminal emulators (xterm, rxvt, gnome-terminal, ...)?

Comment: ya i think there is problem in my text file that i want to display...
thank you so much for helping me out